# Post message to Facebook Friends wall on his/her birthday using sdk 3.0 - ios

Tags: iphone, post, facebook-wall

I am already aware of the fact that we can post to friends wall using Graph API or Feed Dialogue,there are several constraints while doing so:

**Graph API:** We are no longer able to post to other users wall using Graph API since Feb'13!

**Feed Dialogue:** I know we can invoke Feed Dialogue to post to other users wall by mentioning the recipient and clicking share to post a message as shown in the below screen shot:

[image]

But my app requirement is different,there is an option for the user to post to friends wall and also a text view,where the user enters message to post to friends wall on his/her birthday,can any one please provide me any other alternatives to Feed Dialogue as the dialogue should not appear,which means the dialogue appears multiple times based on number of friends!

I have also tried using FBRequestConnection start for post update method i.e.:

```
[FBRequestConnection startForPostStatusUpdate:wallPostView.text place:friend.id tags:nil completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) 
{
  if (!error)
  {
    NSLog(kPostingtoWall);
  }
}];
```

I am facing HTTP error as shown in snap shot below:

[image]

In one word,I want to schedule the message to post on my friends birthday,how to do this,any one please assist me on this,

Thanks all in advance :)

Comment: Please tell me if you solved this problem

Comment: No sunny,I didn't,but I have left the project way back,now I am working on new project :)